# Discord.py bot only replies to one message

Tags: python, discord.py

so im making 2 discord bots: one will listen for commands and when it recieves one it will send a message in a private channel. when the first bot sends a message in that channel the second one will respond to indicate that it's online, then bot 1 requests to start a Minecraft server. the problem is, bot 2 only responds once and if I want it to respond more than once I need to manually restart the code. im on python 3.8.6

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
        
    if message.author.id == bot 1 id:
        if message.content.startswith('<@!bot 2 id>'):
            starterChannel = client.get_channel('private channel')
            channel = message.channel
            if channel == starterChannel:
                await channel.send('ye')
                @client.event
                async def on_message(message):
                    if message.content.startswith('Can'):
                        message = message.content
                        request = message[8:]
                        print(request)
                        if request.startswith('start'):
                            await channel.send('idk how')
```

what's the problem and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (but cannot test, as I do not have an discord bot to test on) that you cannot redefine on_message inside itself and update the client on_message handler. You can try the following instead, which does not declare a new on_message function:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
        
    if message.author.id == bot 1 id:
        if message.content.startswith('<@!bot 2 id>'):
            starterChannel = client.get_channel('private channel')
            channel = message.channel
            if channel == starterChannel:
                await channel.send('ye')

        if message.content.startswith('Can'):
            channel = message.channel
            message = message.content
            request = message[8:]
            print(request)
            if request.startswith('start'):
                await channel.send('idk how')
```

Comment: I made this account to ask this question so it won't show my upvote but this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `await client.process_commands(message)` in the end

Comment: Thanks, but thshea's answer worked for me

Comment: @linkthehero1234 please mark thshea‘s answer as accepted then